# Variadic function without named argument

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I noticed, that both GCC and MSVC are happy with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
void foo(...);

int main()
{
    foo();
}

void foo(...)
{
    std::cout << "foo\n";
}
```

More specifically, code was run under GCC 6.2.0 and Visual Studio 2015.

I know that C requires at least one *named* parameter preceding the ellipsis, which allows to handle any number of arguments using specialized `va_start`, `va_args`, and `va_end` macros from `<stdarg.h>` (here `<cstdarg>`) header. Otherwise, it won't even compile.

Does C++ have some special treatment for "pure ellipsis" form or is it not suitable for fetching the arguments, i.e. it's allowed, but completely impractical?

Comment: When you talk about compilers, mention the *versions* as well.

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks for improving the question.

Comment: Fairly well-formed question but -1 because this is clearly answered on the cppreference documentation for variadic arguments, and it's not clear to me why you didn't simply read it. Should have been the very first stage in your research.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's my bad luck then, I tried with the numerous Google search findings.

Comment: Sometimes instead of quickly searching, you have to _read_ and _study_. We do expect prior research here, and documentation for the feature would seem to be a quite obvious first port of call. Not trying to be rude, just trying to help you with your questions in the future. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[C++ Variadiac arguments are explained here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments). This syntax is supported in C++, but the arguments are not accessible:

> In the C programming language, at least one named parameter must appear before the ellipsis parameter, so `printz(...);` is not valid.
>
> In C++, this form is allowed even though the arguments passed to such
>   function are not accessible, and is commonly used as the fallback
>   overload in SFINAE, exploiting the lowest priority of the ellipsis
>   conversion in overload resolution. This syntax for variadic arguments
>   was introduced in 1987 C++ without the comma before the ellipsis. When
>   C89 adopted function prototypes from C++, it replaced the syntax with
>   one requiring the comma. For compatibility, C++98 accepts both
>   C++-style `f(int n...)` and C-style `f(int n, ...)`

Comment: You were just a bit faster than me, I was about to paste exactly the same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

In C++ it is allowed because even if there is no named parameter before, the `...` will only be an inaccessible variadic argument.

In C, there is no overloads, and having a function that receives only  `...` can be a great source of runtime error. Inaccessible varargs is not useful is C.

In C++, it is currently use as a sink function for sfinae. Compilers will always choose other overload if possible before resolving a call to a function with variadic parameter. It is pratical for sfinae purpose:

```
template<typename F, typename... Ts>
struct is_callable {
private:

    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    static decltype(
        static_cast<void>(std::declval<T>()(std::declval<Args>()...)),
        std::true_type{}
    ) test(int);

    template<typename...>
    static std::false_type test(...); // not a template variadic, classic vararg here.

public:
    // Here, the compiler will try the first version of the function
    // Because '...' is not the preferred overload
    // If the return type expression don't yield to a type, the compiler
    // will have no choice but to pick the variadic one,
    // resulting in a std::false_type
    using type = decltype(test<F, Ts...>(0));
};
```

Comment: Not sure the `(int, double)` example is relevant?

Comment: Well, it shows that c++ is okay with unnamed parameter, and varargs are not different

Comment: They're considerably different. There is almost no relationship between a normal parameter (be it named or otherwise) and a varargs list.

Comment: No problem! :-D